# Youtube - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I'm using the following javascript on [this page](http://mountainfoodstorage.com/index.php/media) in an attempt to switch the video when someone clicks onto the video thumbnail.

```
<script>
    function replaceVideo(id) {
      originalSrc = jQuery(" iframe", "#" + id).attr("src");
      autoPlay = originalSrc + "&autoplay=1";
     jQuery(" iframe", "#" + id).attr("src", autoPlay);
      video = jQuery(" .video-content", "#" + id).html();
     jQuery("#video-page-gray-strip #video-page-content").html("");
      jQuery("#video-page-gray-strip #video-page-content").html(video);
      jQuery(" iframe", "#" + id).attr("src", originalSrc);
    }

    jQuery(".video-list li").click(function() {
      id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
      replaceVideo(id);
    });

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
      if(window.location.search.substring(1)) {
            element = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            if (document.getElementById(element[0])) {
                document.onload = replaceVideo(element[0]);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click onto the thumbnail(s), the video doesn't switch and I get the following console error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://mountainfoodstorage.com/index.php/media from frame with URL
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/OzOvsDVL_Q8?rel=0. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

I'm wondering if I have to change the JS to fix this. If so, how could I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at this: [json-p.org](http://json-p.org/) Keywords are `domain name policy` and `json-p`